# Require.JS + JQuery Plugins + Customer hosted JQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

We've built a platform similar to shopify in which we host customer webpages for eCommerce.

On each page we have some platform javascript which is loaded via requireJS.

This platform javascript uses jquery Cookie as a plugin.

If the customer also installs jQuery it can cause the Cookie plugin to install itself to the customers instance of jQuery rather than our instance of jQuery.

customer html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
```

app.js [our code]:

```
require.config({
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "bower_components/jquery/jquery.min",
        "jquery-cookie": "bower_components/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie",
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery-cookie": ["jquery"]
    }
});
```

platform.js [our code]:

```
define(['jquery', 'jquerye-cookie'], function(jQuery, jQueryCookie) {
    console.dir(jQuery.cookie); // <-- Not available, sometimes
});
```

You can see at the console.dir sometimes jQuery.cookie will not be available, it is because jQuery cookie installs itself into the global $ which may be the customer's version of jQuery or ours.

The only fix I really have is using the compiled version of our platform js at all times. In production this is fine, since our code is compiled together and includes our jQuery dependency our code the execution order is deterministic and at load-time jQuery cookie installs into the correct jQuery object.

The problem is in development this is a PITA to only work on the compiled version of our platform js. Just the compilation time alone slows us down quite a bit.

I'm debating trying to remove all jQuery dependency in our platform JS. I don't want to do that since I'd lose parsley as well. Is there a better solution to avoid this problem?

Update:

noconflict mode won't work because the way jquery cookie (and other jquery plugins) work is:

```
(function ($, document, undefined) {
    $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {
    });
})(jQuery, document);
```

So as you can see even if I re-namespace our jQuery to something like "platform$", the plugin will still load itself into the window.jQuery, which will either be undefined or the customer's version of jQuery.

Edit:

To be clear this is not "a" customer, it is many (eventually thousands, hopefully).

Comment: Does the customer use RequireJS at all?

Comment: It is possible - but generally speaking, no.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the [current code](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js) for the jQuery cookie plugin, I see that it detects whether it is running in an AMD-style loader (which RequireJS is) and uses `define`. This means this plugin does not need a shim.

Now, how could the failure in the question happen?

- A client also uses RequireJS for their code. This means that two configurations are passed to RequireJS. They may clash. RequireJS is not designed to detect such clashes. (So long as the resulting configuration is meaningful to RequireJS, it won't complain.) And depending on how the loading of the two configurations is done, the result may be indeterminate.
- A client does not use RequireJS for their code. If this client *also* incorporates the jQuery cookie plugin in their own code, this would likely create problems because there is no telling what the value of `$` would be at the time their version of the plugin is loaded.

Comment: This is just a typo in my code I posted to stackoverflow. I'll fix it. The actual code doesn't have that typo. Like I said the problem is intermittent failure, and referring to the wrong jquery path would cause 100% failure not intermittent. I have a handle on the problem, I'm very confident it is as I've described and not an oversight with my variable names.

Comment: With what **you** know, it may be true that you can infer that the failure I described would be a 100% one but with the amount of information you've provided in the question, there is no way that **we** can make this inference. For instance, if your client *happens* to have a file named ``jquery.cookie`` located in just the right directory (after all, a lot of people use it), RequireJS will load it. At any rate, I've updated my answer with further thoughts.

Comment: Great catch with the jquery cookie version we just realized our bower was configured for jquery-cookie 1.2 which did not do the AMD check. I've updated to 1.4 which should help with that. Now the only problem is parsleyjs doesn't do the same check. So we still have the same problem with parsley. I think at this time the best thing to do is just fork parsley for our needs and make it properly play with require.

Comment: In the two scenarios you described, #2 is what is happening. I don't think we're interested in handling requirejs collisions at this moment (Scenario #1).

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowing customers to add any HTML content to the page...?  In general, that's a bad idea for security reasons, plus situations like this, where a completely innocent user accidentally breaks your site.  You could try running jquery in noconflict mode http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/ but if the customer can enter in any old javascript, there will always be ways they can break your site's javascript.  So I think the real answer would be to limit what the customers can input.

Comment: Edited my question to show why I don't think noconflict can work. We're trying to enable the customer to have full control of their platform and accept that there are ways they can break their site and interfere with our platform js. However they should not be able to break it JUST by including jQuery. Again this is only a problem in dev mode, in production we just compile our JS and it isn't possible to confound the jQuery namespaces.